# How to calculate new vectorized column from bool and float columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ternary-operator

My DataFrame has a mix of float and boolean:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("C:\....")

df['isActive'] = (df.turns >= 250) & (df.alivePct > 0) & (df.changePct > 0)
```

I want to create a new column where if isActive == false then the value = 0, otherwise the value equals some calculated amount, something like this:

```
df['interestingness'] = (df.changePct * df.alivePct) if df.isActive else 0
```

However because df.isActive is a Series I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

It appears that the ternary if/else operator cannot be used in a vectorized operation.

How else can I do this with manually iterating?

(NOTE: an easy hack is to multiple by df.isActive which will set the value to 0 as False == 0. However I'd like to know a more general solution.)

Comment: what do you mean by more general? also, why is it a hack? it doesn't really get any more general/less hacky than multiplication...

Comment: also, i mean, i see your concern like "what if the bools weren't 0 and 1?" but i would think, yeah, just transform them into zeros and ones and go back to multiplication. the `np.where` solution is good too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
df['interestingness'] = np.where(df.isActive, df.changePct * df.alivePct, 0)
```

For 1D arrays, `np.where(condition, A, B)` is a vectorized equivalent to

```
np.array([a if c else b for a,b,c in zip(condition, A, B)])
```

---

Pandas also provides a [Series.where](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas.Series.where) method which you could use:

```
df['interestingness'] = (df.changePct * df.alivePct).where(df.isActive, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A different solution, maybe not as readable but works.

Create the new column/series:

```
>>> df
   0      1  2
0  1   True  9
1  2  False  9
2  3   True  9
3  4  False  9
4  5   True  9
>>> df[3] = 0
```

Use a mask

```
>>> mask = df[1]
>>> df[3][mask] = (df[0] * df[2])[mask]
>>> df
   0      1  2   3
0  1   True  9   9
1  2  False  9   0
2  3   True  9  27
3  4  False  9   0
4  5   True  9  45
>>>
```